# Problems with "ISynchronizeInvoke" and "this" in C#. I think some sort of Invoke can fix it, but I can't work out how!

Tags: c#

Thank you so much for reading this! I think the fix is relatively easy, but it is beyond me! I can never get my BeginInvokes correct.

I am still learning, and not very good yet, so please don't laugh too hard! As a temporary measure, I am using some public domain code, just to get a feel for what is being done in the code, before I write some similar stuff with only the bits I actually need. However, I do really need the answer if anyone can help. I have uploaded the public domain code to an area of my website, and will link to it later, but I don't think it is necessary, as I have picked out the bits that I think matter below:

My test application works fine, but my main application doesn't. Here is the method I am trying to call:

```
public ProcessCaller(ISynchronizeInvoke isi)
    : base(isi)
{
}
```

Here is the code that calls this method from my test application. This works perfectly.

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        processCaller = new ProcessCaller(this);
        processCaller.FileName = @"..\..\test.exe";
        processCaller.Arguments = "";
        processCaller.StdErrReceived += new DataReceivedHandler(writeStreamInfo);
        processCaller.StdOutReceived += new DataReceivedHandler(writeStreamInfo);
        processCaller.Completed += new EventHandler(processCompletedOrCancelled);
        processCaller.Cancelled += new EventHandler(processCompletedOrCancelled);
        // processCaller.Failed += no event handler for this one, yet.

        // the following function starts a process and returns immediately,
        // thus allowing the form to stay responsive.
        processCaller.Start();  
    }
```

Here is the code to run the same method from the main app. This RunTest is actually called from a BackGroundWorker. I see that this is slightly pointless, but even when I run it directly, removing the extra BackGroundWorker, I still get exactly the same error, outlined below.

```
public void RunTest()
    {
        try
        {
        processCaller = new ProcessCaller(this);
        processCaller.FileName = "test.exe";
        processCaller.Arguments = "/test";
        processCaller.StdErrReceived += new DataReceivedHandler(writeStreamInfo);
        processCaller.StdOutReceived += new DataReceivedHandler(writeStreamInfo);
        processCaller.Completed += new EventHandler(processCompletedOrCancelled);
        processCaller.Cancelled += new EventHandler(processCompletedOrCancelled);
        // processCaller.Failed += no event handler for this one, yet.

        // the following function starts a process and returns immediately,
        // thus allowing the form to stay responsive.
        processCaller.Start();
        }
   }
```

However, this code does not work. The problem is this line. The bit it does not like is "this".

```
processCaller = new ProcessCaller(this);
```

When I try to build, I get two errors:

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'App.Backend.Tools.Test' to 'System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke'

and

The best overloaded method match for 'App.Backend.Tools.ProcessCaller.ProcessCaller(System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke)' has some invalid arguments

I kind of understand the issue. I am not calling this from my GUI or Button (object sender stuff) as in my Test App. I kind of know that I need to Invoke it but I haven't got a clue how to do this! If BeginInvoke/Invoke is the correct course of action, could someone please show me how to do it!?

Thanks so much in advance!

Richard

P.S: Just in case anybody does need it, I have uploaded the public domain code I am using here, but I don't think that anybody does need it.

[AsyncOperation](http://www.niemiro.co.uk/FileShare/AsyncOperation.txt)

[ProcessCaller](http://www.niemiro.co.uk/FileShare/ProcessCaller.txt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter required by the ProcessCaller constructor must be of type `System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke`.  The compiler is telling you that your "this" object (of type `App.Backend.Tools.Test`) does not implement `ISynchronizeInvoke`.

Change your `Test` class definition so that it implements `ISynchronizeInvoke`, something similar to the following:

```
namespace App.Backend.Tools
{
    class Test : System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke
    {
        // Existing code, as well as required implementations
        // of ISynchronizeInvoke members.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. It fixes the issue I described, but not all is quite well! VS underlines the Test : ISyncronizeInvoke (the Test bit only actually) with the error 'App.Backend.Tools.Test' does not implement interface member 'System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke.BeginInvoke(System.Delegate, object[])' and then gives basically the same error for .EndInvoke, .Invoke, and .InvokeRequired. Any ideas? I really appeciate the help.

Comment: Scrap that! You even told me in the comments that I had to implement them! Sorry! Would you please mind telling me how to implement them? Noob question - and poor reading!

Comment: If you click on ISynchronizeInvoke in the class declaration, VS (2008+) should give you a tiny red underline, which expands to a context menu.  Alternatively, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isynchronizeinvoke.aspx for the properties and methods you must implement.

Comment: That fixed it! You beauty! I love you (well - in one sense at least!) Thanks so much! Richard